# SQL Server 2014 Error: Must declare scalar variable? Calling a function within a view

Tags: java, sql-server, database, function, sql-view

I'm having an issue with calling a function within a view I am trying to create. The error that is appearing is "Must declare the scalar variable "@ProductID". The GST in '(Products.Price + GST) AS TotalPrice' is also underlined in red as a problem.
What am I missing?

Here is my function:

```js
CREATE FUNCTION fn_ReturnTaxedPrice
(
 @ProductID int,
 @GST float
) 
 RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @Price float
 DECLARE @GSTPrice float
 SET @Price = (SELECT Price FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID)
 SET @GSTPrice = @Price * (1 - @GST)
 
 RETURN (@GSTPrice)

END
```

Here is my view:

```js
CREATE VIEW vw_SalesDetails
AS
SELECT Sales.SaleNo, 
Sales.SaleDate, 
Customer.FirstName, 
Customer.LastName,
Category.Category, 
Products.ProductDescription, 
Type.Type, 
Products.Year, 
Products.Price,
dbo.fn_ReturnTaxedPrice(@ProductID, 0.1) AS GST,
(Products.Price + GST) AS TotalPrice
FROM Category
JOIN Customer ON Category.CategoryID = Customer.CategoryID
JOIN Sales ON Customer.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
JOIN SalesProducts ON Sales.SaleNo = SalesProducts.SaleNo
JOIN Products ON Products.ProductID = SalesProducts.ProductID
JOIN ProductType ON Products.ProductID = ProductType.ProductID
JOIN Type ON Type.TypeID = ProductType.TypeID
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `@ProductID` in the view ? You supposed to pass in the Product ID from one of the table ?

Answer (score 0):

-- You have to pass ProductId related to table column instead of @ProductID variable.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_SalesDetails
AS
SELECT Sales.SaleNo, 
Sales.SaleDate, `enter code here`
Customer.FirstName, 
Customer.LastName,
Category.Category, 
Products.ProductDescription, 
Type.Type, 
Products.Year, 
Products.Price,
dbo.fn_ReturnTaxedPrice(Products.ProductID, 0.1) AS GST,
(Products.Price + GST) AS TotalPrice
FROM Category
JOIN Customer ON Category.CategoryID = Customer.CategoryID
JOIN Sales ON Customer.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
JOIN SalesProducts ON Sales.SaleNo = SalesProducts.SaleNo
JOIN Products ON Products.ProductID = SalesProducts.ProductID
JOIN ProductType ON Products.ProductID = ProductType.ProductID
JOIN Type ON Type.TypeID = ProductType.TypeID
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_ReturnTaxedPrice
(
    @ProductID int,
    @GST float
) 
    RETURNS money  --this is the correct data type for money
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Price money

    SET @Price = (SELECT Price FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID)

    RETURN @Price * @GST 

END
```

This should work now.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_SalesDetails
AS
SELECT Sales.SaleNo, 
       Sales.SaleDate,
       Customer.FirstName, 
       Customer.LastName,
       Category.Category, 
       Products.ProductDescription, 
       Type.Type, 
       Products.Year, 
       Products.Price,
       dbo.fn_ReturnTaxedPrice(Products.ProductID, 0.1) AS GST, 
       dbo.fn_ReturnTaxedPrice(Products.ProductID, 0.1) + Products.Price AS TotalPrice
FROM Category
       JOIN Customer ON Category.CategoryID = Customer.CategoryID
       JOIN Sales ON Customer.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
       JOIN SalesProducts ON Sales.SaleNo = SalesProducts.SaleNo
       JOIN Products ON Products.ProductID = SalesProducts.ProductID
       JOIN ProductType ON Products.ProductID = ProductType.ProductID
       JOIN Type ON Type.TypeID = ProductType.TypeID
```